# Trimesh get faces centroids / centers

Tags: python, graphics, mesh, trimesh

I am using trimesh python library. I want to overlay face normals ontop of face centroids. Is there any easy way to do that?

Perhaps if there is an external library or helper script that can do this quickly that would also help. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by overlaying face normals. If it's just for visualization use libraries that can visualize normals for you like `meshlab` or `open3d`.

If the question is how to get the face centroids in `trimesh`, there's `mesh.triangles_center`.